# Could Texas Democrats be punished for walking out?

Tags: united-states, law, state-legislatures, texas

The Texas Democrats in the Legislature chose to unite and leave the capitol. The decision was announced an hour before posting.

*Could Texas Democrats be held legally liable when they return?*

Comment: What would they be held liable for?

Comment: Obstruction or something like it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127492/discussion-on-question-by-number-file-could-texas-democrats-be-punished-for-walk). Please don't use comments to debate the question matter. If you would like to answer, please post a real answer. If you would like to discuss, please use the chat function. Please try to limit these comments to suggesting improvements to the question.

Comment: Could answers include jurisdiction of citations showing penalties or punishments?  EG: does Texas' Constitution apply in other states (perhaps via mutual extradition agreements)   Does Sargeant-At-Arms (Giter answer) or Dept of Public Safety (RWW answer) have any authority outside of Texas?

Comment: @JoeW something like "not doing their job"

Comment: @qwr Is that a criminal offense now? Last I checked the only things that can be done for that is impeachment or voting them out and no other punishment.

Comment: I don't know what the legality is but I think the premise of the question is a reasonable inquiry.

Comment: @JoeW That's not totally out of question. For example, teachers strike are illegal in some states (or at least restricted).

Comment: @JoeW " Is that a criminal offense now? "  Obstructing the political process is a crime, and it is this crime that is keeping a lot of people behind bars today.  There is no crime in wearing a helmet with horns to the Senate chambers.  Chasing elected officials out of the room in order to take a selfy from the Senate dais is a crime.  Any elected official removing themselves from the legislative chamber in order to hold up a vote is committing the same crime.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes.  According to this [article](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/elections/texas-democrats-flee-state-effort-block-gop-backed-voting-restrictions-n1273667)

> The lawmakers risk arrest in taking flight. Under the Texas Constitution, the Legislature requires a quorum of two-thirds of lawmakers be present to conduct state business in either chamber. Absent lawmakers can be legally compelled to return to the Capitol, and the source said Democrats expect state Republicans to ask the Department of Public Safety to track them down.

Comment: Does it mention any penalties or punishment, or just that they’d be compelled to return to the Capitol?

Comment: I don't see anything in there about penalties or even how they would force them to return if they are not in the state.

Comment: The first line of the quote is "lawmakers risk arrest in taking flight".  That's how they would be forced.

Comment: Didn't the governor threaten to veto the budget for legislators as a punishment? Is that possible?

Comment: @joew I’d assume they’re out of luck if they leave the state. Republicans in Oregon fled to Idaho last summer and without Idaho’s cooperation there really want anything they could do

Comment: Sure is says they risk arrest but does that mean they are just dragged back to the chambers so the session can take place? My understanding is that the only thing that happens is law enforcement "arrests" them and takes them back so that the legislature can do it's work but there is no long term punishment.

Comment: @r13: they only make about $500 a month that could be suspended.

Comment: So the cops can come, joink them back from the street and drag them to the Capitol, but thats the extend of what they can do?

Comment: They could potentially be held in Contempt of Congress, right? Is that a crime for state legislatures, or just the federal one?

Comment: @dandavis Yes, but this budget doesn't just affect the elected officials in congress, it also affects all of their staff.  Granted it presumably *also* affects all the Republican legislators who *didn't* walk out, and their staffs as well, so it could backfire on him in that way.

Comment: @r13 he didn't just threaten, he actually did veto the portion of the budget that deals with legislative pay (Texas governors have line item veto power). The problem, as Darrrel Hoffman said is that it affects the staff of both parties.  Also, the State Constitution dictates how the actual legislatures are paid so it's actually in question whether the Governor's veto affected the elected officials or just the staff workers.

Comment: @RWW Back in 2003, a large group of legislators did something similar and camped out in Oklahoma to stall legislation and avoid arrest. The governor instructed the treasury to stop paying legislators electronically and use physical checks which had to be signed for in person (this was the official backup process for when the electronic payroll system was down).  He couldn't *refuse* to pay the missing legislators, but he could effectively delay paying them while they were playing hooky.

Comment: @Hobbamok presumably then there will be enough legislators for a quorum, and the majority of the quorum will then remove voting rights from minorities, or whatever they are trying to do.

Answer (score 31):

According to the [Constitution of Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Texas), the Senate and House of the Texas legislature can decide how to compel their members to attend and determine what penalties there are for not attending. For both chambers, the current rules allow the present members to send the Sergeant-at-Arms or some other person to arrest absent members who refuse to appear, and set the conditions for their release. So yes, they can be punished, but it would be a political punishment by their fellow legislators, rather a legal punishment by the judicial system.

The full text of Texas' constitution can be found [here](https://ballotpedia.org/Texas_Constitution), and the relevant part is [Article 3](https://ballotpedia.org/Article_3,_Sections_1-43,_Texas_Constitution), which establishes the Texas legislature, in Section 10:

> Quorum; Adjournments from Day to Day; Compelling Attendance
>
> Two-thirds of each House shall constitute a quorum to do business, but a smaller number may adjourn from day to day, and compel the attendance of absent members, in such manner and under such penalties as each House may provide.

Section 11 also states that each House determines its own procedural rules:

> Rules of Procedure; Expulsion of Member
>
> Each House may determine the rules of its own proceedings, punish members for disorderly conduct, and, with the consent of two-thirds, expel a member, but not a second time for the same offense.

However, since they need a two-thirds quorum in order to 'do business' and decide the punishment, they first need enough of the members who walked out to appear in order reach the quorum. The most recent House rules of procedure, found [here](https://house.texas.gov/_media/pdf/House-Rules-of-Procedure-87.pdf), explain how that could be done in Rule 5, Section 8:

> Sec. 8. Securing a Quorum. When a call of the house is moved for
> one of the above purposes and seconded by 15 members (of whom the
> speaker may be one) and ordered by a majority vote, the main entrance to
> the hall and all other doors leading out of the hall shall be locked and no
> member permitted to leave the house without the written permission of the
> speaker. The names of members present shall be recorded. All absentees
> for whom no sufficient excuse is made may, by order of a majority of those
> present, be sent for and arrested, wherever they may be found, by the
> sergeant-at-arms or an officer appointed by the sergeant-at-arms for that
> purpose, and their attendance shall be secured and retained.
>
> ...
>
> Until a quorum appears, should the roll call fail to show one present,
> no business shall be transacted, except to compel the attendance of absent
> members or to adjourn.

The rules for the Senate, found [here](https://senate.texas.gov/_assets/pdf/SenateRules87-temporary.pdf), are similar, as seen in Article V, rule 5.02:

> Rule 5.02. Two-thirds of all the Senators elected shall constitute a
> quorum, but a smaller number may adjourn or recess from day to day and compel the attendance of absent members (Constitution, Article III, Section 10). In case a less number shall convene, the members present may send the
> Sergeant-at-Arms or any other person or persons for any or all absent members.
>
> ...
>
> The Senate shall determine upon what conditions they shall be discharged. Members who voluntarily appear shall, unless the Senate otherwise directs, be immediately admitted to the floor of the Senate, and they shall report their names to the Secretary to be entered upon the journal as present. Until a quorum appears, should the roll call fail to show one present, no business shall be done except to compel the attendance of absent members or to adjourn.

In short, if there is no two-thirds quorum in either chamber of the Texas legislature, the current rules provide an option for the present members (any number in the Senate, a majority in the House) to have the Sergeant-at-Arms or someone else retrieve the absent members. If the absent members voluntarily appear after being summoned they can proceed as normal, and if not they shall be detained and only discharged according to conditions set by the other legislators.

Comment: Can they establish a punishment without a quorum?

Comment: @Acccumulation : I couldn't find anything in the constitution clarifying that, however the procedural rules for each chamber define what they can do to compel and punish members without a quorum (basically, they can send someone to arrest the absent members). I just added the procedural rules to my answer.

Comment: @Acccumulation I'd guess the decision to arrest and force to attend would be up to the speaker or whatever they call it there, rather than requiring them to all be there and vote on it. In the second case the entire clause would be rather pointless.

Comment: @Acccumulation yes. Here's what they can do without a quorum: "a smaller number may adjourn from day to day, and compel the attendance of absent members, in such manner and under such penalties as each House may provide."

Comment: Do the fleeing legislators have any protection if they're not in Texas? What gives the Sergeant-at-Arms the power to do any of this in other states?